# Display online JSON data on to site with JavaScript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, json, shopify

Hello I need to display some data from an online JSON file to the frontend of my shopify store but however I do it I keep seeing the CORS error. Does anybody know how I can go about this in the correct way or a way around it?

This is a snippet of how I was trying to attempt it:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
       var url = 'text/javascript" src="https://******/admin/customers.json';
var j = [];
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) { j = data;},
  async: false
});

alert(j);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow. 14+ years of Shopify and still CORS questions. Obviously, you cannot call /admin from the front-end of your Shopify store. That would be silly as you need to then expose your API keys to the world, and that world is nasty. Someone could erase your shop or turn it into a fancy emporium selling peanuts in the shell for $10 each.

If you want to show off customer data to customers use Liquid. If you cannot figure out Liquid, and you must do callbacks to the /admin, you use an App, and a Proxy.